# What's an easy example of a family of three commuting contractions for which there's no isometric dilation but fulfill the von Neumann inequality?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, contraction-operator

Or the other way around, an example of a family of three commuting contractions for which there exists an isometric dilation, but which does not satisfy the von Neumann inequality?

The only example I've come across is Parrot's example in "Unitary dilations for commuting contractions", where you take:

$$T_1 = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\ I&0\end{pmatrix}$$

$$T_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\ U&0\end{pmatrix}$$

$$T_3 = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\ V&0\end{pmatrix}$$

where U and V are two non commuting unitary operators. Here, the family $T_1, T_2, T_3$ does not have an isometric dilation, but it satisfies the von Neumann inequality.

Nevertheless, it turned out to be not that easy to prove this, so my question is, is there any other such example which is easier to prove?

Comment: What inequality do you mean?  The von Neumann's inequality I find in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%27s_inequality) is for one contraction.  Are you asking for $\|p(T_1,T_2,T_3)\| \le \sup\{|p(z_1,z_2,z_3)| : (z_1,z_2,z_3) \in \mathbb D^3\}$ for polynomials $p$ in three  variables?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, exactly this one